# How to merge 2 tables in PowerQuery using substrings?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a sold items table. In this list, in addition to the name of the product, there are other expressions required by law - all on a single line.

In the second table I have the name of the products.

I need to merge the product name from the second table with the items from the first table. However, as the items in the first table are in the middle of a sentence, something like "product" == "%product%" would be needed.

How to do this merge in PowerQuery?

Example tables

```
+------------------------------+
|Sold items                    |
+------------------------------+
|Yellow bananas - consume soon |
|A box of small apples         |
|Blue and yellow pencil set    |
|A box of oranges              |
+------------------------------+

+---------+
|Products |
+---------+
|Bananas  |
|Apple    |
|Juice    |
|Pencil   |
+---------+
```

Expected outcome:

```
+------------------------------+----------+
|Sold items                    | Products |
+------------------------------+----------+
|Yellow bananas - consume soon | Bananas  |
|A box of small apples         | Apple    |
|Blue and yellow pencil set    | Pencil   |
|A box of oranges              | (null)   |
+------------------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Result

[image]

Add a column:

[image]

```
Table.SelectRows(Table2,  (x)=> Text.Contains ([Sold items], x[Products], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
```

Then expand.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Sold items", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows(Table2,  (x)=> Text.Contains ([Sold items], x[Products], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Products"}, {"Products"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: Where should I enter the final code? I expanded the table but the product records came up null.

Comment: You add a new column and enter it exactly as I have written and then simply expand. If the records are empty, you have either not copied it correctly or the table names are incorrect.

Comment: David, I checked all the names and they are correct. And still zeros are coming. Any further suggestions on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: David, I found my mistake! When copying the items from my question here on StackOverflow to Excel, the items in the table were with a space character at the end of each item and then when searching for the occurrence they could not find it. I applied the TRIM function and it fixed everything.

Your solution was perfect!

Thank you very much!